# js function does on work on setting doctype specification

Tags: javascript, html, doctype

I am new to javascript.Itried to make this page but somehow *shorten* function does not work on providing doctype specification.I am using this one

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Frameset//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/frameset.dtd">
```

but without specifcation it works fine
following is full code of file:

```
<html>
<head>
<script language="javascript" >
function show(){
document.getElementById("dynamic").style.display="block";
document.getElementById("dynamic").style.opacity=1;
document.getElementById("dynamic").innerHTML="<table><tr>\n\t<td>Enter current password:</td><td><input type=\"password\" name=\"ppass\" size=\"45\"></td></tr><tr>\n<td>Enter new password:</td><td><input type=\"password\" name=\"npass1\" size=\"45\"></td></tr><tr>\n<td>Confirm password:</td><td><input type=\"password\" name=\"npass2\" size=\"45\"></td></tr><tr><td colspan=2><input type=submit value=\"Save\"></tr></table>\n";
document.setting.question[1].checked=true;
}
function hide(){
    if(document.forms.setting.question[0].checked!=true){
        fade("dynamic",50);
        }
    }
function appear(){
    document.getElementById("dynamic").style.display="block";
    document.getElementById("dynamic").style.opacity=1;
    document.getElementById("dynamic").innerHTML="<table><tr>\n\t<td>Enter password:</td><td><input type=\"password\" name=\"ppass\" size=\"45\"></td></tr><tr><td>Security Question:</td><td><input type=\"text\" name=\"ques\" size=\"100\"></td></tr><tr><td>Answer:</td><td><input type=\"password\" name=\"ans\" size=\"10\"></td></tr><tr><td colspan=2><input type=submit value=Save></tr></table>";
    document.setting.pass[1].checked=true;
    }
function disappear(){
    if(document.forms.setting.pass[1].checked){
        slide("dynamic",50);
        }
    }
function fade(id,time){
    var i=0;
    for(;i<10;i++){
        setTimeout("document.getElementById('dynamic').style.opacity-=0.1",(i*time));
        }
    i--;
    setTimeout("gayab("+id+")",(i*time));
    }
function gayab(id){
    id.style.display="none";
    id.innerHTML="";
    id.style.opacity=1;
    }
function slide(id,time){
    var i=1;
    document.getElementById(id).style.height=150;
    var b=document.getElementById(id).style.height;
    for(;i<15;i++){
        var j="shorten("+id+","+i+")";
        var k=i*time;
        setTimeout(j,k);
        }
    var j="gone("+id+")";
    var k=i*time;
    setTimeout(j,k);
    }
function shorten(id,i){
    id.style.height=(15-i)*10;
    }
function gone(id){
    id.style.display="none";
    id.style.height=150;
    }
</script>
<noscript>You are Using an Outdated Browser.<br>Please Update Your Browser</noscript>
<style>
.options{float:left;}
#dynamic{float:right;background-color:rgb(210,205,236);height:150px;opacity:1;overflow:hidden;width:720px;display:none;}
.nofloat{clear:both;}
</style>
<title>Settings</title>
</head>
<body>

<p align=right><a href=home.php>HOME</a> <a href=newpass.php>Change Password</a> <a href=logout.php>Log Out</a></p>
<form action="changepass.php" method="post" name="setting">
<div class=options>
<table>
<tr>
    <td>Change Password:</td>
    <td><input type="radio" name="pass" onClick="show();" value="1" id="Yes"><label for="Yes">Yes</label></td>
    <td><input type="radio" name="pass" onClick="hide();" value="0" id ="No" CHECKED><label for="No">No</label><br></td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td>Change Security Question:</td>
    <td><input type="radio" name="question" onClick="appear();" value="1" id="yes"><label for="yes">Yes</label></td>
    <td><input type="radio" name="question" onClick="disappear();" value="0" id="no" CHECKED><label for="no">No</label></td>
</tr>
</table>
</div>
<div id="dynamic"></div>
<div class=nofloat>
<a href=logout.php>Logout</a>
</div>
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

please help.

Comment: `<noscript>You are Using an Outdated Browser.<br>Please Update Your Browser</noscript>` — It is possible for people to disable JavaScript without having an "outdated" browser. It is also possible for people to use the latest version of a browser (Lynx for example) and not have JavaScript support. In general you should [build on things that work](http://icant.co.uk/articles/pragmatic-progressive-enhancement/) and if you are going to fail to do that, then you should ensure your error messages are at least accurate.

Comment: One _huge_ point that I can't stress enough is that you're using `id` to refer sometimes to a string and sometimes to an element. That's really not recommended. The `setTimeout` code further muddles things -- whether you want to pass a string or a DOM node, use something like `setTimeout(function() { slide("dynamic"); }, 1000)` instead of these `eval`-ish expressions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your Doctype (despite being inappropriate for the document since it don't consist of a frameset) is triggering Standards mode.

This is a good thing as it massively reduces inconsistency between different browsers (and between browsers and standards).

In standards mode, most browsers will follow the CSS specification and treat things like `height: 27` as an error to be ignored instead of an error to be corrected to `height: 27px`.

The obvious problem with your code (there may be others, you have posted a *lot* of code) is that you are assigning numbers to CSS properties with JavaScript … and numbers don't have units.

To take just one example:

```
id.style.height=150;
```

should be:

```
id.style.height = "150px";
```

You make a similar mistake in at least one other place.

Answer (score 1):

You are setting a document type which expects your page to [consist of framesets](http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/sgml/framesetdtd.html), yet there are none there. You should use a different `DOCTYPE`, for example [transitional](http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/sgml/loosedtd.html) instead.